To refer an interface property as a parameter value to another functional component
How to refer an interface property as a parameter value to another functional component
interface InterfaceProperties {
  interfaceProperty1Id: number,
  interfaceProperty1Name : string
}

const tabsInterfaces: Map<InterfaceDetailEnum, JSX.Element> = new Map<
  InterfaceDetailEnum,
  JSX.Element
>([
  [InterfaceDetailEnum.Detail, <InterfaceDetailMessages id={} name={} />],
  [InterfaceDetailEnum.Type, <></>],
  [InterfaceDetailEnum.Both, <></>]
]);

I want to pass the interface properties in the below line.
<InterfaceDetailMessages id={} name={} />]

That means, in id, I want to pass interfaceProperty1Id and in name I want to pass interfaceProperty1Name properties.

interfaceProperty1Id and interfaceProperty1Name are types, not values, so they are not passed as values. Please [edit] to clarify what you are trying to accomplish and what the specific issue or problem is. If you are just needing to pass prop values then do just that, e.g. InterfaceDetailMessages id={123} name="abc" />.

You can have factory methods in your map instead of JSX.Element themself:
const empty = (props: InterfaceProperties) => <></>

const tabsInterfaces: Map<InterfaceDetailEnum, (props: InterfaceProperties) => JSX.Element> = new Map<InterfaceDetailEnum, (props: InterfaceProperties) => JSX.Element>([
  [InterfaceDetailEnum.Detail, props => <InterfaceDetailMessages id={props.interfaceProperty1Id} name={props.interfaceProperty1Name}/>],
  [InterfaceDetailEnum.Type, empty],
  [InterfaceDetailEnum.Both, empty]
])

It means you do not create any component yet, you are going to do it in a render():
export default function YourComponent() {
  const iProperties: InterfaceProperties = {interfaceProperty1Id: 1, interfaceProperty1Name: "name"} // derived from parent
  const detail: InterfaceDetailEnum = InterfaceDetailEnum.Detail // could derive from parent as well

  // map.get() has value | undefined return type
  // in case of undefined fallback to factory method which creates empty JSX.Element
  const factoryMethodToCreateTheJsxElement = tabsInterfaces.get(detail) || empty

  // now we instantiate the element
  const tab: JSX.Element = factoryMethodToCreateTheJsxElement(iProperties)
  return (
    <div>
      {tab}
    </div>
  )
}

